# Difference between Python 2.6.4 and Python 3.1.2 integer handling

Tags: python, variables

Why does

```
x = 15
if (x/2) * 2 == x:
    print 'Even'
else: print 'Odd'
```

Evaluate to **Odd** in Python 2.6.4?

While in 3.1.2 (with parentheses around print statements of course) is evaluates to **Even**?

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2.x, the `/` operator uses integer division by default. Since Python 3.x (or if you start your 2.x program with `from __future__ import division`), the `/` operator performs floating-point division. This is documented in [PEP238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

You should use `//` if you want integer division, or start your programs with `from __future__ import division` if you want floating point division under 2.x.

Note that the generic way to check whether a number is even or odd is modulo division with the `%` operator; like this:

```
x = 15
print ('even' if x % 2 == 0 else 'odd')
```

For details on these and other operators, refer to the [Python manual](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

Answer (score 2):

The `/` operator performs integer division in Python 2.x, while it does floating-point division in Python 3.x.  You can use `//` to get integer division.

Checking the parity of an integer is easier using the modulo operator:

```
if x % 2:
    print("odd")
else:
    print("even")
```